# @OnTimer method receives null references when fired

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I've been recently dealing with an issue that has been driving me crazy as it is just happening once deployed in Dataflow but never in local where everything works flawlessly. FYI, I'm using Apache Beam `2.9.0`.

I'm defining a DoFn step which buffers event for a certain period of time, say 5 minutes, and after that time it fires some logic.

```java
@StateId("bufferSize")
private final StateSpec<ValueState<Integer>> bufferSizeSpec =
  StateSpecs.value(VarIntCoder.of());

@StateId("eventsBuffer")
private final StateSpec<BagState<String>> eventsBufferSpec =
  StateSpecs.bag(StringUtf8Coder.of());

@TimerId("trigger")
private final TimerSpec triggerSpec = 
  TimerSpecs.timer(TimeDomain.PROCESSING_TIME);
```

I've got my `processElement` logic to add incoming events...

```java
@ProcessElement
public void processElement(
    ProcessContext processContext,
    @StateId("bufferSize") ValueState<Integer> bufferSize,
    @StateId("eventsBuffer") BagState<String> eventsBuffer,
    @TimerId("trigger") Timer triggerTimer) {

  triggerTimer.offset(Duration.standardMinutes(1)).setRelative();
  int size = ObjectUtils.firstNonNull(bufferSize.read(), 0);
  eventsBuffer.add(processContext.element().getValue());
  bufferSize.write(++size);
}
```

And then my trigger...

```java
@OnTimer("trigger")
public void onExpiry(
    @StateId("bufferSize") ValueState<Integer> bufferSize,
    @StateId("eventsBuffer") BagState<String> eventsBuffer) throws Exception {

  doSomethingHere();
}
```

Whenever `onExpiry` is executed, the parameters that it receives are null and 0.

What could be going on cluster-wise?

**EDIT**:

Window used prior the DoFn.

```java
.apply(
  "1min Window",
  Window
    .<KV<String, String>>into(
        FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1)))
    .triggering(AfterProcessingTime
                  .pastFirstElementInPane()
                  .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(1)))
    .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO)
    .accumulatingFiredPanes())
```

Comment: Would strongly recommend increasing the SDK version in general. Are you running this  in stream mode or batch mode?

Comment: Thanks for the response @RezaRokni, I'm running this in stream mode. The reason why I'm using such 2.9 is because with Dataflow and a newer version (gotta try with newest release tho as the most recent one that I tried was 2.11 as far as I can remember) would fail once deployed as an error in the logs appear related to not being able to assign resources or lost connection with cluster. Will search for the issue and paste.

Comment: What windowing are you using before this call, or are you doing this in the Global Window.

Comment: Just edited the question @RezaRokni

Comment: Could you do a quick test where you set the Fixed window to be something like 10 mins. Need to check my understanding of something as I have mostly worked with EventTime triggers

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note that state is held for a key-window tuple when the window expires the state will be GC'd.

So For key-1 your Bag object will have data for {key-1, TimeInterval-1} , {key-1,TimeInterval-2} etc..

If you want strong semantics between the input values and your timer, you may want to explore the use of a EventTime timer.